# Powershell: setting environment variable Path local to script only and not session

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

In my script, when I do

```
$env:Path = "Some Path"
```

and I execute my script within the ISE, $env:Path for the ISE session is now set to "Some Path". I would like to modify the $env:Path for the script only, making it revert back to the original value in the ISE session,after the execution of the script. Right now, I have to close and restart the ISE.

The idea is to change the environment for the scope of my script only. If there is a better idiom in Powershell, please let me know.

Comment: Use the script [scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You could always just save the original path, and reset it back at the end of the script...

```
$origPath = $env:Path
$env:Path = "Some Path"

<script>

$env:Path = $origPath
```